# How to insert latex code to a kable in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I was able to insert `\\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\\color{blue}{$\\updownarrow$}}}` to the `fig.cap` of a graphic but for some unknown reason, I get errors when trying to insert it into the caption of a kable. Could someone point out what am I doing wrong? Below is a small example.

````
---
title: "Greek"
output: pdf_document
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(kableExtra)

```
## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

```{r,fig.width=11,echo=FALSE}
kable(mtcars[1:5,], "latex",label="tab1",booktabs = T,
caption="Nice Graphic {\\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\\color{blue}{$\\updownarrow$}}}") %>% kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped","HOLD_position"),stripe_color = "pink!25")
```
````

I tried to insert only the blue arrow without \Acrobatmenu and it works but as soon as I insert it I get an error message.

Comment: You have an anser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75588841/10215301), and do not post a duplicate question... https://stackoverflow.com/q/75560669/10215301

Comment: I apologize, will delete this one.