# How to insert latex Acrobatmenu to kable

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I was able to put a blue greek letter on the caption of my `kable`. Could someone help me to put on the `kable` caption the following latex arrow instead of alpha? `{\\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\\color{blue}{$\\updownarrow$}}}`

**This works:**

````
---
title: "Acrobatmenu"
output: pdf_document
date: '2023-02-24'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,comment = "")
```

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. 

```{r}
kable(mtcars[1:5,], "latex",booktabs = T,caption = "This is a nice graphic \\color{blue}$\\alpha$") %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped","HOLD_position"),stripe_color = "pink!25") 
```
````

**But this does not work:**

````
---
title: "Acrobatmenu"
output: pdf_document
date: '2023-02-24'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,comment = "")
```

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. 

```{r}
kable(mtcars[1:5,], "latex",booktabs = T,caption = "This is a nice graphic {\\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\\color{blue}{$\\updownarrow$}}}") %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped","HOLD_position"),stripe_color = "pink!25") 
```
````

Answer (score 0):

As I have already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75588756/10215301), use `\protect` before `\Acrobatmenu{...}{...}` inside `\caption{...}` to let `\Acrobatmenu{...}{...}` expand later. Furthermore, remove `{}` surrounding `\Acrobatmenu{...}{...}`.

````
---
title: "Acrobatmenu"
output: pdf_document
date: '2023-02-24'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,comment = "")
```

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. 

```{r}
kable(mtcars[1:5,], "latex",booktabs = T,caption = "This is a nice graphic \\protect\\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\\color{blue}{$\\updownarrow$}}") %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped","HOLD_position"),stripe_color = "pink!25") 
```
````

[image]