# How to insert latex expression in kable

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I would like to include a latex expression in the caption option of kable. However, I am getting an undefined error message. I am able to include the latex expression inside the function `add_header_above` and works as expected but when I try the same expression in kable(caption=) rmarkdown fails. I have a reproducible example below: The first table works fine but the second one doesn't work.

````
---
title: "Latex Expression"
output: pdf_document
date: '2023-02-24'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,comment = "")
```

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. 

**LATEX EXPRESSION WORKS FINE**
```{r}
kable(mtcars[1:5,], format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, caption="Another table with Acrobat") %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped","HOLD_position")) %>%
  add_header_above(c("\\\\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\\\\color{blue}{$\\\\updownarrow$}}"=12), align = "r", escape = FALSE)
```

**GET AN ERROR HERE**
```{r}
kable(mtcars[1:5,], format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, caption="This is a graphic \\\\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\\\\color{blue}{$\\\\updownarrow$}}") %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped","HOLD_position"))
```
````

The goal is to get an upanddown latex arrow right next to table caption. I can accomplish this by adding an extra header on the table but I prefer to get the arrow next to the caption. See snapshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `\\`, not `\\\\`,  to escape LaTeX command in `kable(caption = "....")`. Moreover, you have to `\protect` the command `\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\color{blue}{$\updownarrow$}}` in the caption.

````
---
title: "Latex Expression"
output: pdf_document
date: '2023-02-24'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, comment = "")
```

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. 

```{r}
kable(
  mtcars[1:5, ],
  format = "latex",
  booktabs = TRUE,
  caption = "This is a graphic \\protect\\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{\\color{blue}{$\\updownarrow$}}"
) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "HOLD_position"))
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Carlos, I didnt know about \protect. I have used \\\\ because it doesnt work with \\ on other sections of my document. Really appreciate it.